# How to create a dependency bundle?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I want to create a bundle of dependencies to easily include in other cargo projects.

Say I have three different libraries: engine_logger, engine_files, engine_bench.
Is it possible to bundle them together into a dependency called engine_essentials?

```ini
    #cargo.toml
    #So that I can simply do: 
    [dependencies]
    engine_essentials
    #instead of:
    #engine_logger = {path = "crates/engine_logger"}
    #engine_files  = {path = "crates/engine_files"}
    #engine_bench  = {path = "crates/engine_bench:}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a library named `engine_essentials` which depends on the other three and *reexports* them; its source code would consist of `src/lib.rs`:

```rust
pub use engine_logger as logger;
pub use engine_files as files;
pub use engine_bench as bench;
```

Or you could reexport the *contents* of all three, but this risks running into name conflicts if the 3 libraries have any common module names (`common`, `utils`, `prelude`, that sort of thing):

```rust
pub use engine_logger::*;
pub use engine_files::*;
pub use engine_bench::*;
```